GORM - How to use a custom interface?
package models

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type GormQueryBuilder interface {
    FindQueryBuilder(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB
}

type BaseInterface interface {
    Get(GormQueryBuilder, *gorm.DB) error
}

type Base struct {
    gorm.Model
    BaseInterface    `gorm:"-"`
    GormQueryBuilder `gorm:"-"`
}

func (b *Base) Get(i GormQueryBuilder, db *gorm.DB) error {
    return i.FindQueryBuilder(db).Find(&i).Error
}

type A struct {
    Base
    B B `gorm:"..."`
}

func (c *A) FindQueryBuilder(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return db.Preload("B")
}

func GetA(c echo.Context) error {
    tx := db.DB().Begin()
    defer tx.Commit()

    a := A{}
    if err := c.Bind(&a); err != nil {
        return c.NoContent(http.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    x := a.Get(&a, tx)
    print(x)

    // rest of the code
}

value of X is a gorm error unsupported data
what am i doing wrong exactly?
I am trying to use my custom interface, such that I lessen the amount of code significantly.
The idea is, i can have each model build specific queries using the interface GormQueryBuilder.
Then i pass the object to the base functions which will automatically fetch the built queries and whatnot...

Try changing .Find(&i) to .Find(i).

Thank, you I think this solved the issue.
